# Is it possible to search for a year in a date range with MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, search

Given is data which contains a period of time, spanning years. Just like this:

```
| ID | Name               | Alive                 |
|----|--------------------|-----------------------|
| 1  | Washington, George | 1732-02-22/1799-12-14 |
| 2  | Adams, John        | 1735-10-30/1826-07-04 |
| 3  | Jefferson, Thomas  | 1743-04-13/1826-07-04 |
  …
```

Is it possible to store this data in MySQL in a way that a search for an intermediate date (over all fields, just a year), like the search term `1788`, yields results?

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    alive DATERANGE
);

SELECT * FROM t WHERE * LIKE '%1788%'
```

The only solution I see is to add another column which contains a list of years, (`1732,1733,`…) but I guess there are better solutions. Do I need the date in one field or twos, and what’s the column type I need for this to work? Can I have under specified date ranges in that column (such as `1155/1227`) or do I have to rewrite them before insert (like `1155-01-01/1227-12-31`)?

Border matches shall be returned as well. A search for the string `1799` should still return George Washington, even though he was not alive from 1st of January until 31st of December inclusively. I guess this is rather simple since it is a string match already.

Comment: You should have start date and end date in two separate columns to begin with, and use a proper date column type instead of text.

Comment: I agree with @CBroe, you can then `select * from t where YEAR(startDate)  = 1788 OR  YEAR(endDate)  = 1788`

Comment: @TheFlash You should make your comment an answer and replace `=` by `><`, it’s the *range* I was looking for.

Comment: @Paramaeleon I added an answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit your data then I suggest changing it to fields Born & Died if not then we can use the `LEFT` and `INSTR` functions for Born and the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` functions for Died.

```
SELECT ID, Name, Alive, 
LEFT([ColName],INSTR([Alive],"/")-1) AS Born, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(Alive,'/',-1) AS Died
FROM t
```

Which will split out Born and Died dates:

```
| ID | Name               | Alive                 | Born       | Died       |
|----|--------------------|-----------------------|------------|------------|
| 1  | Washington, George | 1732-02-22/1799-12-14 | 1732-02-22 | 1799-12-14 |
| 2  | Adams, John        | 1735-10-30/1826-07-04 | 1735-10-30 | 1826-07-04 |
| 3  | Jefferson, Thomas  | 1743-04-13/1826-07-04 | 1743-04-13 | 1826-07-04 |
```

Then you can use:

```
WHERE Alive LIKE '%1788%'
```

To search dates.

Or individually as Born:

```
WHERE LEFT([ColName],INSTR([Alive],"/")-1) LIKE '%1788%'
```

Died:

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Alive,'/',-1) LIKE '%1788%'
```

Or if you just wanted the years in the Born and Died fields use an additional `LEFT` function:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Alive, 
LEFT(LEFT([ColName],INSTR([Alive],"/")-1),4) AS Born, 
LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Alive,'/',-1),4) AS Died
FROM t
```

Which would give you:

```
| ID | Name               | Alive                 | Born | Died |
|----|--------------------|-----------------------|------|------|
| 1  | Washington, George | 1732-02-22/1799-12-14 | 1732 | 1799 |
| 2  | Adams, John        | 1735-10-30/1826-07-04 | 1735 | 1826 |
| 3  | Jefferson, Thomas  | 1743-04-13/1826-07-04 | 1743 | 1826 |
```

EDIT:

you can use the `BETWEEN` function the other way around for that.

```
SELECT ID, Name, Alive, 
LEFT(LEFT([ColName],INSTR([Alive],"/")-1),4) AS Born, 
LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Alive,'/',-1),4) AS Died
FROM t
WHERE 1788 BETWEEN LEFT(LEFT([ColName],INSTR([Alive],"/")-1),4) AND LEFT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Alive,'/',-1),4)
```

Comment: The last one is closest to what I need for, just of course `WHERE Born >= '%1788%' AND Died <= '%1788%'` was what I meant by find in *range*.

Comment: @Paramaeleon Added another query

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need the date in one field or twos

Definitely two, `birth` and `death`, and use the predicate `BETWEEN ... AND ...` for your searches. It’s less expensive than to split a field in twos at every query and it makes better use of indexes.

> and what’s the column type I need for this to work

That’s trickier. I would normally definitely agree with comments saying that you must use `date` fields, for a variety of well known good reasons. However, it is obvious from your question that you are interested only in years and effectively disregard the actual dates; furthermore, you are dealing with historic data that might be incomplete: missing days or even months are usual in this context; such incomplete dates can be stored in `date` fields but return `NULL` on some operations, which might create problems; when you have a `date` field you cannot create an index on the year, so your queries would all be full table scans. In short, *in your particular case*, I’d go for `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` for the years and `CHAR(5)` to store the less useful month-and-day info, just in case you might need it in the future, to build a real date on the fly with `CAST(CONCAT(year,'-', month_and_day) AS DATE)`.
In conclusion, this is the design I propose:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    birth_year SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    birth_md CHAR(5),
    death_year SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
    death_md CHAR(5) 
);

CREATE INDEX t_ndx ON t(birth_year, death_year);

SELECT * FROM t WHERE 1788 BETWEEN birth_year AND death_year;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @CBroe suggested - you should have two columns instead(`startDate` & `endDate` OR `bornDate` & `DeathDate`), you can then write your query this way:

```
select * from t where YEAR(startDate) >= 1788 OR YEAR(endDate) <= 1788
```